# Webpack: How to inject javascript into the HTML instead of separate JS file

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Is there a way to have webpack inject the output into the HTML instead of a separate file?

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // webpack puts the output here
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to use the `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin`. https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inlineSource: '.(js|css)$' // embed all javascript and css inline
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
]
```

Comment: Works! But with version 4.39 of webpack it was initially throwing an error. It was solved by using the beta version: `html-webpack-inline-source-plugin@1.0.0-beta.2` and using it with: `new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin)`.

Comment: Does not work anymore

Comment: @Dr.Random which version of webpack, node and the plugins are you using?

Comment: I installed all the latest a couple of days ago.