# Can I directly inject Javascript into an HTML file with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, html-webpack-plugin

I need to create a standalone HTML file (so no `<script src="main.js"></script>` tags.

I am using some node_modules and in development, writing it in separate files, but I want to be able to create a `webpack.config.js` that allows me to directly put the javascript into `.html` file. I know of HTMLWepackPlugin, but that only create a script tag that includes a source, not actually put the HTML in the file (even with inject: true).

Is there a workaround or another Wepack plugin?

Comment: [html-webpack-inline-source-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin). _"This is an extension plugin for the webpack plugin html-webpack-plugin. It allows you to embed javascript and css source inline."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Webpack: How to inject javascript into the HTML instead of separate JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52846031/webpack-how-to-inject-javascript-into-the-html-instead-of-separate-js-file)

Use html-webpack-inline-source-plugin, it is an extension plugin for the html-webpack-plugin functionality by adding the {inlineSource: 'regex string'} option.

[Git plugin link](https://github.com/DustinJackson/html-webpack-inline-source-plugin)